# NSWindowController showWindow only works once

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I have a subclass of NSWindowController that has its own nib and another class that has an `IBAction` to show the window and loads it like so.

```
if (!propertiesController){
    propertiesController = [[PropertiesController alloc] init];
}
[propertiesController showWindow:self];
```

It the first time but after I close the window and call this method again the window is not displayed. I am sure the window is not getting released. Do I possibly have to override `showWindow` to order the window to the front? Or do I have to specify what window the controller uses in the nib?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried

```
[propertiesController.window makeKeyAndOrderFront:self];
```

?